# JPA @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED): Missing class for indicator field value

Tags: inheritance, jpa

Is it possible to have a default implementation when no class is provided for an indicator field value for not raising this exception?

```
Missing class for indicator field value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not defined in JPA, but some providers do support more complex indicators.

If using EclipseLink, you can use a ClassExtractor to define your own code to determine the Class to use for each row.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#No_class_discriminator_column